# Conditional Searching in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have three fields to be searched inside a mongodb database. Sometimes I have to search based on only one field, sometimes two and sometimes three as well. It is something like-if there is only one field value present, then search on the basis of only one field, if two are there then find using like $and and if three all of the three,find using like $and. Is there any single query to make the search working?

[the below is the image where i should make selection from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t29Ip.png)

Comment: Please provide some sample document (as text, not as screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a query string like below,

```js
let queryString = {};
if (field1 !== undefined) {
  queryString.field1 = field1;
}
if (field2 !== undefined) {
  queryString.field2 = field2;
}
if (field3 !== undefined) {
  queryString.field3 = field3;
}



let documents = await db.find({ $and: [queryString] }).exec();
```